# Configuring Jenkins with Cloud TFS (Supports GIT)

Tags: tfs, jenkins

We are trying to configure Cloud TFS (Project Created with Git Support) & Jenkins (Ubuntu Machine).

When ever i try to enter the Repository URL it gives the following error.

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h
>   https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/xyzrepo.git HEAD"
>   returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: fatal: Authentication
>   failed

I have generated keys using SSH route, but unfortunately i can't add the key @ Cloud TFS Repo.

I have even tried this format https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Repo_Name but somehow was not successful.

PS: Bare minimum's are installed (GIT & Git plugin for Jenkins)

Any help/instructions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable Alternate Credentials in tfs.
Have a look at this [howto](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/use-git-and-xcode-with-tfs.aspx)

Comment: It's a really good idea when linking to other tutorials/documents to include the most relevant part here in case the link changes or the site is no longer available in the future.

Comment: i did...but the problem i posted is with connecting TFS with Jenkins... I'm using GIt Plugin in Jenkins...which is unable to connect TFS.

Comment: For me it worked as long as I enabled for alternate logons, and authenticate using https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Repo_Name. IE: This should be your git repo in config. If that doesnt cover it, try to download git-credentialstore from Codeplex. It did the trick for several of our developers connecting to TFS-Git in VS. [link](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/)